# when run make in Momentics on windows I got error

Tags: qnx, momentics

When running cmake in  Momentics 6.5 on Windows I got the following error:

bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create! 
bash: Run_cmake: No such file or directory

Note: I have /tmp, /temp set in my environment variable to my appData/local/....

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: 1. why don't you just do "mkdir /tmp" from the bash prompt? that should resolve its complaint. Likely your bash is not looking at the environment variables when looking for the /tmp directory.  Rather, it is looking for it wherever bash thinks "/" is located. 2. what is it that you are trying to build?  QNX momentics is using GNU make, which is shipped as part of the host toolchain.  If you are building a BSP you should run "make" not cmake.

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to CMake or Momentics. Are you using MinGM? What's the software stack you use?

Comment: did you get it fixed? I get the same error message

Comment: sorry for the late response. I got it fixed by reinstalling Momentics.